# Java пользовательские слушатели

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, listener

Мне нужна помощь со слушателем в Java. Я пишу простенькую библиотеку упрощающую создание сервера на Java.

Добавил несколько методов: `onClientConnected(Client client)`, `onClientDisconnected(Client client)`, `onMessageReceived(Client client, String message)`.

Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь написал сам код, который будет действовать в этих случаях, заранее использовав переданные параметры?

Тоже самое работает с кнопкой в Swing: `jButton.addActionListenner(ActionEvent e)`, где я могу сразу пользоваться возможностями объекта `e`.

P.S. Я пытался искать об этом информацию в Интернете, но так ничего и не понял. Видимо, пришло время научиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вам нужен [шаблон проектирования `Observer`(Наблюдатель)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) - надо завести поле для хранения слушателя, который снаружи будет обрабатывать соответствующие события, происходящие внутри какого-либо класса (у вас это, видимо, сервер):

```java
public interface ServerListener {
    void onClientConnected(Client client);
}

public class Server {
    private ServerListner listener = null;

    public void setServerListener(ServerListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void onClientConnected(Client client) {
        if( this.listener != null ) {
            this.listener.onClientConnected(client);
        }
    }
}
```

Где-то в другом месте:

```java
Server server = new Server();

// Регистрируем анонимный объект-обработчик
server.setServerListener(new ServerListener() {
    void onClientConnected(Client client) {
        // обработка события
    }
});
```

Comment: Да, это то, что мне нужно. Однако, я не понимаю, как вызвать `onClientConnected` из класса `Client`, передав в параметры `this`?

Comment: @Артём откуда и куда надо передать `this`?

Comment: я разобрался сам. Спасибо огромное, Вы помогли!